# List comprehension to list Sudoku blocks

Tags: python, list-comprehension, sudoku

I am trying to define the blocks in a *sudoku* grid. So for example a 4x4 sudoku has 4 Blocks of 2x2.

What I have now is:

```
import itertools
import math

lines = [[1,0,3,4],[4,0,2,1],[2,1,4,3],[3,4,1,2]]
length = len(lines[0])
sqrt = int(math.sqrt(length))
blocks = [[lines[r+i][c+j] for i,j in itertools.product(range(0, length, sqrt), repeat = 2)]
     for r,c in itertools.product(range(sqrt), repeat = 2)]
```

But I can't seem to get the list comprehension correct, because the output of blocks is:

```
[[1,3,2,4],[0,4,1,3],[4,2,3,1],[0,1,4,2]]
```

But it should be:

```
[[1,0,4,0],[3,4,2,1],[2,1,3,4],[4,3,1,2]]
```

Can someone maybe help me with this?

Comment: nested list comprehensions are difficult to write and very difficult to read. Do you _have_ to use a list comprehension? Why not just write a short loop that is both easier to write and easier to read?

Comment: You do not really specify how the input maps to the output? What do you aim to generate? Care to explain?

Comment: How did you reach at the required output?

Comment: Why do you need two loops for this? Just step every other list and do the transform that way.

Comment: Just don't, that line is quite difficult to read. Unless there's a reason to not do it, always prefer a cleaner code/more readable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to perform a tiling, meaning that the input `[[a,b,c,d],[e,f,g,h],[i,j,k,l],[m,n,o,p]]` or more conveniently:

```
+--+--+
|ab|cd|
|ef|gh|
+--+--+
|ij|kl|
|mn|op|
+--+--+
```

is transformed into: `[[a,b,e,f],[c,d,g,h],[i,j,m,n],[k,l,o,p]]`.

I think you reversed the logic of your nested lists:

- The outer lists should consider the *block* identifiers *bi,bj*, thus:

  ```
  [... for bi,bj in itertools.product(range(0,length,sqrt), repeat = 2)]
  ```
- whereas the inner list comprehension should iterate over the cells:

  ```
  [lines[bi+i][bj+j] for i,j in itertools.product(range(sqrt), repeat = 2)]
  ```

Combining these gives:

```
[[lines[bi+i][bj+j] for i,j in itertools.product(range(sqrt), repeat = 2)] for bi,bj in itertools.product(range(0,length,sqrt), repeat = 2)]
```

or more convenient to read:

```
[
    [lines[bi+i][bj+j] for i,j in itertools.product(range(sqrt), repeat = 2)]
    for bi,bj in itertools.product(range(0,length,sqrt), repeat = 2)
]
```

Using Pythons interactive shell:

```
>>> [[lines[bi+i][bj+j] for i,j in itertools.product(range(sqrt), repeat = 2)] for bi,bj in itertools.product(range(0,length,sqrt), repeat = 2)]
[[1, 0, 4, 0], [3, 4, 2, 1], [2, 1, 3, 4], [4, 3, 1, 2]]
```

which looks like the expected output.